# What is best for an URL: upper case or only lower case

Tags: seo, url, case-sensitive

At this time we have URLs formed with upper cases like this:

```
mywebsite.com/us/Fine-Art/
```

And we want to add artist names like Van Gogh, so is the best for SEO to continue with a mixed of upper case and lower cases, like this:

```
mywebsite.com/us/Fine-Art/Van-Gogh
```

Or only lower cases for the artist name

```
mywebsite.com/us/Fine-Art/van-gogh
```

Or maybe remove all upper cases, even to what is already indexed by search engines, we will perform 301 redirections to new urls :

```
mywebsite.com/us/fine-art/van-gogh
```

Answer (score -1):

Go with lower case always, avoid uppercases, underscores, parameters etc.

Comment: This answer doesn't offer any sources or reasons why this is true. You should update your answer to include more information.

Comment: Yes but I think he is right, when I take a look at what is done by my competitors with the same type of URLs, they never use uppercases.

Comment: We would like all answers here to have explanations and references.  Right or not, this answer is not very useful.  It could be improved by explaining why it is true, elaborating on personal experience with such URLs, and adding links to references.  I'm not going to delete this answer, but I did down-vote it.  If the author improves it, I'd be happy to reverse my vote.